# SQL syntax error when doing two tables jointure on something

Tags: sql, join

I have this SQL script:

```
update fs
set user_id = table_B.id,
    message = substring(fs.message, 1, charindex('[', fs.message)-1)
from edi_file_steps fs 
inner join GU_User u on u.login = substring(fs.message, charindex('[', fs.message) + 1, len(fs.message) - charindex('[', fs.message) - 1)
where message like '%Downloaded%' ;
```

I am getting a SQL syntax error at line 4 near on

```
u.login = substring...
```

What is my syntax error? I want to use pure (non vendor-specific) SQL syntax.

I tried this with mysql and hsqlb and I am getting the same error.

Could someone help me with this ?

Comment: You don't need the line `from edi_file_steps fs`. Just remove it and alter your query so it starts like this: `update edi_file_steps fs`

Comment: always the same problem, syntax error

Comment: The inner join was also in the wrong position.

`update
  edi_file_steps fs
  inner join GU_User u on u.login = substring(
    fs.message,
    charindex('[', fs.message) + 1,
    len(fs.message) - charindex('[', fs.message) - 1
  )
set
  user_id = table_B.id,
  message = substring(fs.message, 1, charindex('[', fs.message) -1)
where
  message like '%Downloaded%';`

Comment: yes thanks, write an answer so I can accept it for you :)